# An Asus Prime B660M motherboard, no Wifi or Bluetooth Adapter found when trying live Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.10 prior to installation

Tags: wireless, kernel, bluetooth, asus, motherboard

UPDATE: burned an Ubuntu 22.04 USB live boot, and got both wifi and bluetooth; installed OS,still works.

Bought new computer.

Motherboard is ASUS PRIME B660M-A AC D4 Micro-ATX Motherboard,
seems to have Intel Wireless-AC 9462 and I think (not sure) it is a combined wifi/bluetooth.

From my research, this should not be a problem since Linux kernel versions 4+.

I could not find this hardware in the linux hardware database website.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below lines in terminal-

- sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
- sudo apt autoremove
- sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

Re-installing the utility/device drivers may fix the issue. This has resolved my same issue.

Comment: How can this solve the problem? `unity-control-center` is obsolete and unrelated.